# Inbox page button link not open with querystring

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-email

I am send email with amy page - In my page I have one button - on click that is opening my website - I am sending some querystring data ....that is not coming to email to open page

I am sening code ....

`oMail.Body += "<a href=\"http://www.bankerbay.com/Admin/IntroductionConformation.aspx?match_Id=\"" + match_ID + "> <input type=\"button\"  style=\"background-color:#126DA8; font-family:Aparajita; font-size:large; color:White\"  value=\"I Agree to be Introduced \" onclick=\"" /> </a> ";`

exp :

- 1.You will come at my site ....
- 2.you will fill some information ....
- 3.Our website send you one email with submit button (html button code)....
- 4.when you will click that button in your email.....
- 5 you will come again at my site with some

  code .....I need that code ....for process next task .....I am not
  able to send code with querystring .

please check it where is mistake ?

I means  ....Using c# to send html email with Button included querystring  in email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `input` tag with image or text. `input` tag in html email is really useless.

```
    oMail.Body += " " + " <a href=\"http://www.bankerbay.com/Admin/IntroductionConformation.aspx?match_Id=\""‌​+ 
match_ID + " ><img src=\"http://www.bankerbay.com/images/myimage.png\" /></a>";
```

***P.S.** Use string.format instead of +.*

Comment: Sorry that I was out of town. I just found a typo in your code. If you still have a problem, replace `?match_Id=\""‌​+ match_ID + "` with `?match_Id=" + match_ID + "\"`. ***Result will be*** - `oMail.Body += " <a href=\"http://www.bankerbay.com/Admin/IntroductionConformation.aspx?match_Id=" + match_ID + "\" ><img src=\"http://www.bankerbay.com/images/myimage.png\" /></a>";`